# Possible gitignore issue for setting up a new OpenXR project with MRTK to do Unity-Hololens dev

Tags: unity-game-engine, gitignore, hololens, mrtk, openxr

I am following the instructions on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/new-openxr-project-with-mrtk) page to set up my `Unity` project for developing an app for `Hololens2`.

Once I switched platform and saved the new settings, I was curious to see what changes had been made under the hood by looking at my `SourceTree` modified files, but there is none. I have made a lot of changes to `Build Settings` and `Player Settings`.

Is this normal (i.e. are such settings supposed to be ignored) or there is something wrong with my `gitignore` file that stops these changes from being tracked and registered?

Where are the changes to `Build Settings` and `Player Settings` stored? **Should they be kept under version control?**

Answer (score 1):

If you have a doubt about a possible `.gitignore` rule which would explain why no change is shown, type:

```
cd/ path/to/repository
git check-ignore -v -- a/file/which/should/have/changed
```

If it is ignored, that command will show you the ignore file and line of the ignore rule in it.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I actually do not know where these settings would be stored. My guess would be in the `XRSettings.asset` file, but not sure at all. The command `git check-ignore -v -- XRSettings.asset` does not return anything...

Comment: If it does return nothing, it means the file is not being ignored.